# different way to add method to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

today, i saw following code in a node.js example.  the part that got me really confused is "userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password)".

I think this just adds a new method to the userSchema object.  but why do you need .methods there.

whats the difference between these two?

userSchema.generateHash = function(password)

or

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password)

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local: {
        email: String,
        password: String,       
    },
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
    },
    twitter: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        displayName: String,
        username: String
    },
    google: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String
    }
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password){
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: See: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html, the part about "instance methods".

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thank you so much.  this is exactly what i m looking for.